# Locker Service seems to break result of function on object passed to component method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have a constructor defined in a static resource script file. It exposes a single function that returns a Promise. When I instantiate an instance and pass it to a method on a component, Locker Service seems to be wrapping the Promise that is returned, causing it to no longer work.

> Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$LockerTestComp$controller$execute [args.context.getPromise(...).then is not a function] Failing descriptor: {c$LockerTestComp$controller$execute}. Please try again.

If I change the code to call $then$ instead (probably a bad idea), then I get:

> Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$LockerTestComp$controller$execute [# is not a promise] Failing descriptor: {c$LockerTestComp$controller$execute}. Please try again.

If I disable LockerService, then it works.

Do component methods only support primitives? Or is the Locker Service overstepping its bounds?

**LockerTestComp.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.LockerTest}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:method name="execute" action="c.execute">
        <aura:attribute name="context" type="object" />
    </aura:method>
    Hello World
</aura:component>
```

**LockerTestCompController**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.execute(new lockerTest());
    },
    execute : function(component, event, helper) {
        var args = event.getParams().arguments;
        args.context.getPromise().then(function() { alert('success') });
    }
})
```

**LockerTest.js** (static resource)

```
window.lockerTest = function() {
    this.getPromise = function(name) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve() });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an issue within the LockerService filtering logic where it incorrectly returns a non-Promise object to your controller file. Should be a simple fix. If you file a support ticket you can have them reference our internal work item W-3402504 to track the fix.